# Failure build on Maven release plugin

Tags: java, git, maven

I'm new to Maven and I'm assigned in a multi module project working with parent pom file. I wanted to change the snapshot project to a release. Even if I added scm tag and the Maven release plugin, the release:prepare goal keeps on failing.

This is what I added on the parent pom.xml file:

```
 <project>
        ...
        <scm>
            <developerConnection>scm:git:http://localhost:8181/gitblit
             /r/server/myCompany.git</developerConnection>
        </scm>
        ...


        //And the plugin:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
        <project>
```

Here is the error:

The error is this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-            
          plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on 
          project myParentProject: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which command you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install git, obviously!

If your OS is UNIX-like, use some sort of package manager,
`apt-get install git` for debian derivatives and ubuntu.

If your OS is Windows, also make sure that `git.exe` is on `%PATH`.

Comment: I installed a gitblit repository on a server and modified the scm tag as                                   <developerConnection>scm:git:http://192.168.2.45:8181/gitblit/repositories/</developerConnection>                                                                                      but still showing the same error.

Comment: @Dera I expect you need to install git locally. I'm afraid Maven won't be able to talk to gitblit without git executable.

Answer (score 0):

Please install GIT first, then try again